# What is the best way to search in sockets in Node.Js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking

I have an array called 'players'.
and i push every socket that join my server by :

```
players.push(socket);
```

i use this method for search for other sockets :

```
for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
                if (socket != players[i]) {
                    ...
                }
            }
```

but someone told me that this method is not right i should do something like this:

```
var socketID = uniqid();
if( !players[ socketID ] ) players[ socketID ] = socket;
socket.socketID = socketID;
```

but i can't understand this please someone explain for me :)
thank's and sorry for my bad english

*uniqid() generates random string.

Comment: later approach stores sockets on string index which can help you to access socket object in array with single pick. like you can check if(players[socket.socketID]){....}, it eliminates your need to iterate through array

Comment: so if we want find other sockets ( not current socket ) we must do like this ?
if(players[socket.socketID] != socket.socketID) { ... }
right ?

Comment: for that matter you can iterate to find all other sockets

Comment: I'm a bit confused ... when i log 'typeof players[ socketID ]' it says Undefined. what players[ socketID ] exactly is ? :D